# jQuery dynamic table creation table structure not comes correctly

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I am creating a dynamic table using `jQuery` as follows.

```
$('#dynamictable').append('<table>');
var table = $('#dynamictable').children();
for (var i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
    table.append("<tr>");
    for (var j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
        table.append("<td style='background:#ccc;'>cell</td>");
    }
    table.append("</tr>");
}
$('#dynamictable').append('</table>');
```

The table seems to come ok. But when I inspected the **table structure is not coming correctly**.

It comes like the follows:

[image]

Which is not correct.
Check my fiddle for details: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YxMJT/2679/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are appending `<tr>` it is adding the `</tr>` to the code. Same for `</tr>` also.

You should do this way -

```
for (var i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
    var str = "<tr>";
    for (var j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
        str += "<td style='background:#ccc;'>cell</td>";
    }
    str += "</tr>";
    table.append(str);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YxMJT/2682/)

Comment: Thanks buddy it helped!!

Comment: take a look on this link also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34012904/jquery-dynamically-created-table-need-to-add-ids-dynamically-to-tds

Comment: Check the answer there.

Answer (score 1):

You are appending `td` directly to `table` instead of adding to `tr` and then adding `tr` to `table`. This is why the html you have td as direct child of table. Make a `tr` object add *tds* to it and then add this `tr` to table will make correct html

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/YxMJT/2685/)

```
$('#dynamictable').append('<table>');
var table = $('#dynamictable').children();
for (var i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
    tr = $("<tr />");
    for (var j = 0; j < 7; j++) 
        tr.append("<td style='background:#ccc;'>cell</td>");  
    table.append(tr);
}
$('#dynamictable').append('</table>');
```

Comment: Thats the main issue. :)