# jQuery dynamically created table need to add id's dynamically to <td>'s

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I have created a table using jQuery as follows:

```
$('#dynamictable').append('<table>');
var table = $('#dynamictable').children();
for (var i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
    var str = "<tr>";
    for (var j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
        str += "<td style='background:#ccc;'>cell</td>";
    }
    str += "</tr>";
    table.append(str);
}
$('#dynamictable').append('</table>');
```

Here I have **13*7 = 91** `<td>`s.

I want to add id to the `<td>` dynamically from **0 to 90**. How can I do that?

Check fiddle: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YxMJT/2682/)

Comment: Just use `str += "<td id='i_" + i + "_j_" + j + "' style='background:#ccc;'>cell</td>";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this also -

```
var id = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
    var str = "<tr>";
    for (var j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
        str += "<td id='" + id + "' style='background:#ccc;'>cell</td>";
        id++;
    }
    str += "</tr>";
    table.append(str);
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YxMJT/2686/)

Comment: buddy thanks once again. 2 answers solved half my problems!!

Comment: Well, just keep in mind that `ID` are not supposed to start with a  number. add a prefix before concatenating the id, like `'id=column_' + id`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code

```
$('#dynamictable').append('<table>');
var table = $('#dynamictable').children();
var count = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 13; i++) {

    var str = "<tr>";
    for (var j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
        count = count + 1;
        str += "<td style='background:#ccc;' id='td_id_"+count+"'>cell</td>";
    }
    str += "</tr>";
    table.append(str);
}
$('#dynamictable').append('</table>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the simplest way I would do it is like this:

```
var index=0;
$("#dynamictable table td").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("id", index++);
});
```

[Here is the update **JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/YxMJT/2688/)

In the JSFiddle, clicking on the button adds `ids` to the `tds`, you may check it in the inspect-element view :)